# Create a PDF document

Tags: pdf, tml

I wish to send a letter to my prospective client. By inputting 
Email ID and Person Name and postal address able to send an email with PDF attachment. 
I have one letter template in word.

How to do.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this question related to tml? It seems like a general/generic question. Kindly be specific with your question as per your tagging. And if you have doubt then ask questions, StackOverflow is not to learn to program. You can find the solution to your question in many different tutorials.

Answer (score -2):

An easy way to create a PDF is to use Google Docs. Open up a word document in Google docs and then simply export as PDF.

Great article about this [here](https://oregonstate.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=45811).